# How can I make a field default a value with every new record?

Tags: mysql

I have an HTML form to insert (`$_POST`) a new record to MySQL.

I have a field that always needs the value `"FC"`.  Do I make this happen in phpMyAdmin or do I insert `"FC"` at the time when I insert the record via HTML form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just perform this query:

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` ALTER `fieldname` SET DEFAULT 'FC';
```

Supposing that you have `tablename` table and `fieldname`

Comment: Thank you..  This works, but I decided to add a hidden field with a value.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has the option to specify a `default` value for columns. Edit the column and set `default` to `As defined:` and put `'FC'` in the field.

For consistency you might also want to insert 'FC' in the form since the default value will not be used if something else is provided.

Or if you really want to limit the value only to 'FC' then why not hardcode it into your query?